kafka jmx statistics: internal topic that I would like to know what it is for
I am running a small distributed kafka cluster, Sydney: sidOne, sidTwo, sidThree
I've got some kafka connect workers running on a separate VM: conOne, conTwo.
All of this I'm monitoring using prometheus JMX plugin, that is then displayed on grafana.
What I'd like to know is what is the origin of the following topics:
{job="Sydney", service="sidOne"}
{job="Sydney", service="sidTwo"}
{job="Sydney", service="sidThree"}

All of them are recording non-zero messages per second (50+) which is in line with some of the topics that are being pushed into kafka. Part of me wonders if its the replication, but I'd like to know rather than just assume.
